# Can I import a palette in scale_fill_distiller?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I need to plot seismic intensities on a map. I can do that by :

```
data = as.data.frame(cbind('MMI'= c(5.705595,7.161231, 5.187135, 6.454477, 6.027840, 4.217181, 4.704672, 5.146932, 5.327897, 7.113057), 'LON'= c(-116.4, -116.5, -116.6, -116.7, -116.8, -116.9, -117.0,-117.1, -117.2, -117.3), 'LAT'= c(34.5, 34.5, 34.5, 34.5, 34.5, 34.5, 34.6, 34.6, 34.6, 34.6)))

my_map = get_map(location = c(lon = mean(data$LON), lat = mean(data$LAT)), zoom = 9, maptype = "satellite", source = "google")
ggmap(my_map) + geom_tile(data = data, aes(x=LON, y=LAT, fill = MMI), alpha = 0.5,color = NA) + scale_fill_distiller(palette = "Spectral", limits = c(0, 10), direction =-1)
```

My problem is that intensities have a defined color palette from 0 to 10 (I listed it in the "colours" vector), but I do not manage to use this palette in scale_fill_distiller.
I also tried to use scale_fill_manual, but it returns me an error.

```
colours = c("#FFFFFF", "#9999FF", "#66FFFF", "#66FFCC", "#99FF33", "#FFFF33", "#FFCC33", "#FF9900", "#FF6600", "#FF0000", "#CC0000")

ggmap(my_map) + geom_tile(data = data, aes(x=LON, y=LAT, fill = MMI), alpha = 0.5, color = NA) + scale_fill_manual(values = colours)
```

> ```
> > Error: Continuous value supplied to discrete scale
> ```

Any Suggestion?

Comment: change your data using as.factor to avoid to supply continuous value to a discrete scale

Comment: Any particular reason you're using the `limits` argument in your `scale_fill_distriller`?

Comment: the color scale goes from 0 to 10, but my data don't, so i need the values to be associated with the right color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I would use a gradient where one could define colors (and breaks). The following example uses default breaks, but you can control them using `values` argument.

```
scale_fill_gradientn(colours = colours)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you it solved my problem! I did use:   
`scale_fill_gradientn (colours = colours, values = rescale(c(0,2,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10.5)),  limits=c(0,10))`